# New domains websites not under another domains directory Plesk 11

Tags: domains, plesk

i am trying to build up my new server and found some strange behaviour in the hosting configuration.
I created a user for my websites and logged in. Then i created my first domain entry webspace1.com. When i now add a new domain it needs a Document root setting but this is always inside the first created domains webspace.

/var/www/vhosts/webspace1.com/httpdocs is the document root for the main entry like it should be.
When i now add a new Domain webspace2.com plesk creates a directory /var/www/vhosts/webspace2.com with some directories like it should be. But my web root lies under
/var/www/vhosts/webspace1.com/example2.com/.

Can i configure it so that the newly created domains get their webspace inside their own directory like it was in older versions of plesk? Or must i then make another account for every single domain i create?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you want their docroots be inside their own directories, you would need to create new account for every new domain. To understand it easier - consider your old domain a primary domain or account in new Plesk and your 2nd domain a "secondary domain" inside primary one.

Comment: That sounds ok but why is plesk then using another directory outside the primary domain to save the settings, private, subdomains etc. where it should be. It doesnt really make sense to make it so complicated when it already was simpler before.